# Is is possible for input file control to work with ".lnk" shortcut files?

Tags: html

Question. My client want to be able to select shortcut lnk files in upload ( input  + type file )control. By default control gets file that shortcut is pointing to. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something below with `accept` attribute of html input.

```
<input type="file" name="pic" accept=".js">
```

Comment: Wow! I actually needed it for "non pure html" solution, but it works like charm. Many thanks!